# Xcode: how can I enable Metal API Validation for a tests target?

Tags: ios, xcode, metal

It's easy to enable Metal API validation when running my app via Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> Metal API Validation: [Xcode logging: "Metal API Validation Enabled"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645401/xcode-logging-metal-api-validation-enabled/60645489)

But what about for testing? There is no such setting in Edit Scheme -> Test, and validation appears to be off when I run tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the METAL_DEVICE_WRAPPER_TYPE environment variable to 1 in Edit Scheme -> Test -> Arguments.

Comment: Hi Taylor, do you know how to disable "Metal API Validation Enabled" or remove this message this appears in my debug console.

Comment: @Sanjeevcn To disable Metal API Validation, click on your scheme at the top of the window, go to Edit Scheme > Diagnostics > Metal API Validation. There will be a checkbox that you can untick.