# Xcode logging: "Metal API Validation Enabled"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, metal, oslog

I'm building a macOS app via Xcode. Every time I build, I get the log output:

> Metal API Validation Enabled

To my knowledge my app is not using any Metal features. I'm not using hardware-accelerated 3D graphics or shaders or video game features or anything like that.

Why is Xcode printing Metal API log output?

Is Metal being used in my app? Can I or should I disable it?

How can I **disable** this "Metal API Validation Enabled" log message?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Toggle Metal API Validation via your Xcode Scheme:

> Scheme > Edit Scheme... > Run > Diagnostics > Metal API Validation.

It's a checkbox, so the possible options are `Enabled` or `Disabled`.

Disabling sets the key `enableGPUValidationMode = 1` in your `.xcscheme` file.

After disabling, Xcode no longer logs the "Metal API Validation Enabled" log message.

**Note:** In Xcode 11 and below, the option appears in the "Options" tab of the Scheme Editor (instead of the "Diagnostics" tab).

Comment: What's it for..?

Comment: Scheme > Edit Scheme... > Run > Options > Metal API Validation.

Answer (score 13):

#### How to disable the message:

Select your scheme at the top of the window. Click `Edit Scheme` in the drop-down, go to `Diagnostics` and untick the `Metal API Validation` checkbox.

#### Is Metal being used in my app?

Yes, even if your code isn't interacting directly with the GPU, many high-level frameworks do -- specifically `Core Image`, `SpriteKit`, and `SceneKit`. For example, I narrowed the pesky "Metal API Validation Enabled" message in my app down to this line:

```swift
layer.backgroundColor = NSColor(patternImage: image).cgColor
```

#### Should I disable Metal API validation?

Enabling validation makes every Metal API call be checked, which causes a "[small, but measurable, impact on CPU performance.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/diagnosing_metal_programming_issues_early)" The purpose of this validation is to

> check for code that calls the Metal API incorrectly, including errors in resource creation, encoding Metal commands, and other common tasks.

There's a very low chance that Apple frameworks like Core Image are using the Metal API incorrectly, so if your app only uses those high-level Apple frameworks, then I'd say you should feel safe to disable API validation. Getting rid of that damn output message is worth the risk.

Comment: Great detail that the `NSColor`, etc., APIs are triggering the logging.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same message.

I had a `.onDelete(perform: deleteLocations)` at the end of a scrollview closure.

I changed the scrollview to a list and the message went away.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started to work for an update to my macos app.

It worked well without errors but then i added a storyboard file from an older xcode project and when i fire .loadWindow() i saw these on my log:

> - "Metal API Validation Enabled"
> - "fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)"

Then i looked at the interface builder and one of my labels was in a weird position.
So i centered that label and run app again and the **"fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)"** warning gone.
It still says **"Metal API Validation Enabled"** whenever i load that window from that .storyboard file but that doesn't bother me.

So i think this is something about how operating system is drawing windows and views or maybe something about interface builder version difference.