# Different UIView inside TabView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created a TabView and use PageTabViewStyle() to display different UIViews.

Here is the code:

```
var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            TabView() {
                ForEach(0..<imageNames.count) { index in
                    TextInfoView(imageName: imageNames[index],
                                 text: texts[index],
                                 title: titles[index],
                                 titleSymbol: titleSymbols[index])
                }
                ContactView() // <-- another view 
            }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            .navigationTitle(pageTitle)
        }
    }
```

The TextInfoView is just a view for displaying information with images and text.

When I add another View that is "ContactView()" another customView with some images and text, I receive the following warnings:

> 2021-04-01 23:39:54.581457+0800 Metal API Validation Enabled

What this message mean?

Note that my ContactView() has a MKMapView() there. If I remove the MKMapView(), then there is no such error.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645401/xcode-logging-metal-api-validation-enabled, but please note this is not really a "warning", its just an informational message that Metal is being used (with validation enabled)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode logging: "Metal API Validation Enabled"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645401/xcode-logging-metal-api-validation-enabled)