# MetalPlugin Issues: MetalPluginName property or is of the wrong type

Tags: swift, metal, createml

I have been getting two messages on running my application. The app not only launches but functions as it should, however, I would rather sort the issues now rather than some crash in the future.

The messages are:

1. Unable to locate MetalPluginName property or is of the wrong type
2. +[MTLIOAccelDevice registerDevices]: Zero Metal services found

Could anyone help with the messages and how to remove them.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same here. Since upgraded to Xcode 12.5.

Comment: If you are not using Metal, you can turn off the Metal API check which eliminates that error. See [Xcode logging: “Metal API Validation Enabled”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645401/xcode-logging-metal-api-validation-enabled)

Comment: Sorry to but in on this question, but I AM writing a program for Metal, and I'd like to get rid of these messages while still keeping Metal API Validation enabled. I understand I need to set `MetalPluginName` and `MetalPluginClassName` but where and to what values?

Comment: visual studio 2002 is stable and better than Xcode on 2021. it's like this from Xcode 4.